# Theming the iframe scroller bar

Tags: javascript, iframe, svg, scrollbar

All,

In our web application, we have an iFrame that loads SVG. The browser automatically add the scroller bar when the user zooms into the SVG using the controls in our web application. Now we want to theme this 'dynamic' scrollbar so that it's look is in line with the rest of the interface.

I have looked at a few options in jquery such as the '[jscrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/#support)' & '[jquery custom scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html)', however, our problem is that we are using ECMA script with our SVG, whereas jquery is javascript based, needless to say, we are unable to theme the scrollbar using the jquery based solutions. Has anyone any suggestions of alternatives that could theme the iFrame scrollbar?

many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The only way to affect the normal scrollbars are using Microsoft IE specific proerties.

You can see more here http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/coloring_scrollbars_using_styles_css_properties.php3

But that probabrlu do not work in all browsers.

The alternative is to use a scrollbar component that uses overflow:hidden + javascript to create your own scrollbar.

And I do not know of any of those for SVG.

The examples for jQuery you ha uses this later tecnique, it's not the normal browser scrollbars but rather div layers and images.

In your case you might be able to use them if you place the ifram inside a div that uses the jQuery solution to scroll.  Then make the iframe as large as the SVG, that way you scroll the whole iframe window within the div layer.

Comment: Thank you David for teh detailed feedback. I did look into the 'put the SVG' in a html div but that does not work with the SVG & ECMA script code that I have in the application.

any thoughts on how to go about code the 'overflow: hidden' idea you brought about?

Comment: I'll see if I can code up something that scrolls an iframe in a div but it might take a day as I have my hand full during weekends with the kids. But try googling for scroll clipped iframe and see if you find any ready made scripts, they are probably more complete than what I might manage to whip up ;)